# Setting non-numeric variable values for a drop-down list form component

Tags: java, install4j

I need to set non-numeric variable values from a drop-down list form component, i.e.:

if 0 then = "x"
if 1 then = "y"

I then use variable for value written to property file.
I know it is basic coding but I have only been able to get 0 or 1 value written, not variable I am trying to declare.

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate the numeric value to another variable. For example, you can add a "Set a variable" action to the form with the following script:

```
int value = (Integer)context.getVariable("dropDownVariable");
switch (value) {
    case 0:
        return "x";
    case 1:
        return "y";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.valueOf(value));
}
```